# Find specific string sections in python

Tags: python, string, indexing

I want to be able to grab sections of strings with a function. Here is an example:

```
def get_sec(s1,s2,first='{',last='}'):
    start = s2.index(first)
    end = -(len(s2) - s2.index(last)) + 1
    a = "".join(s2.split(first + last))
    b = s1[:start] + s1[end:]
    print a
    print b
    if a == b:
        return s1[start:end] 
    else:
        print "The strings did not match up"
string = 'contentonemore'
finder = 'content{}more'
print get_sec(string,finder)
#'one'
```

So that example works...my issue is I want multiple sections, not just one. So my function needs to be able to work for any amount of sections, for example:

```
test_str = 'contwotentonemorethree'
test_find = 'con{}tent{}more{}'
print get_sec(test_str,test_find)
#['one','two','three']
```

any ideas on how I can make that function work for an arbitrary number of replacements?

Comment: I would look into using regex http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html with Python .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the standard python [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) library

```
import re
a = re.search('con(.*)tent(.*)more(.*)','contwotentonemorethree')
print a.groups()
# ('two', 'one', 'three')
```

or
    print re.findall('con(.*)tent(.*)more(.*)','contwotentonemorethree')
    # [('two', 'one', 'three')]

**edit:**
you can escape special character in a string using

```
re.escape(str)
```

example:

```
part1 = re.escape('con(')
part2 = re.escape('(tent')
print re.findall(part1 + '(.*)' + part2,'con(two)tent')
```

Comment: wait, this doesn't work in all situations...if there are parenthesis around something, it returns it twice: `>>> a = re.search('con((.*))tent(.*)more(.*)','con(two)tentonemorethree')
>>> a.groups()
('(two)', '(two)', 'one', 'three')`

Comment: @RyanSaxe yes if the parenthesis are part of the text you need to backslash them. See http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#matching-characters

Comment: What do you mean ? regular expression is a way to express string patterns. To do so it uses special characters. If you want to match these special characters, you have to escape them. Here the parenthesis means save this part of information, any character `.`, appearing 0 or multiple time `*`, in a group `(...)`. In your example you were using "{}" to symbolize the string section. How would you deal with "con{{}}tent" ?

Comment: If you know there will be parenthesis in the strings you want to match, then it depends how you construct the pattern, but you can probably escape them automatically.

Comment: fair enough, I reaccepted your answer. I just wanted a function that would always work without a regex input, but clearly the regex statement has to change depending on the way the string is formatted

Answer (score 1):

It is not just "use regex". you are trying to actually *implement* regex. well, the easiest way for implemeting regex will be using the `re` library. of course.

Answer (score 0):

ummm use regex?

```
import re
re.findall("con(.*)tent(.*)more(.*)",my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something with regular expressions.

Here's python's page about regular expressions: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

As an example, if say you knew that the string would only be broken into segments *"con"*, *"tent"*, *"more"* you could have:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"(con).*(tent).*(more).*")

s = 'conxxxxtentxxxxxmore'

match = regex.match(s)
```

Then find the indices of the matches with:

```
index1 = s.index(match.group(1))
index2 = s.index(match.group(2))
index3 = s.index(match.group(3))
```

Or if you wanted to find the locations of the other characters (.*):

```
regex = re.compile(r"con(.*)tent(.*)more(.*)")
```